# How to add {,},[,] brackets to regex pattern to allow them as special characters

Tags: c#, regex

I am having this below regex pattern. I want to allow these below characters as special characters.

- {
- }
- [
- ]

`Regex regEx = new Regex(@"^(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[!@#$%^&*()+_<>~-])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-z]).{8,15}$");`

Is there a way to add them

Comment: What is your problem? The braces and square brackets [are allowed with your pattern](https://regex101.com/r/O6xJW7/1).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Are you sure about that?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen And what do you think a `.` matches?

Comment: `\]`,`\[`, `\{` and `\}`

Comment: You're right...but I think the OP was asking how to add them to one of the character classes.  In other words, _require_ that they appear.  Water under the bridge anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to escape them within the regex. Within a regular expression, you can refer to `"\["` to get a `'['` character, for example.

Note that in C, C#, C++, Java, etc, you usually need to double up the `'\'` character to escape the escape character. So when adding `'['` to your regex, you would actually use `"\\["`. In your case you're using an `@""` so you've escaped that trap.

Comment: OP is using an `@` prefixed string - no need for doubling up slashes

Comment: None of the chars OP wants to add requires escaping if placed correctly inside the pattern. If they should be added at all since the current pattern already "allows" any char but line break chars.

Comment: @JamesThorpe - you're right. In the regex hash, I missed that. I'll update response.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I think he has a bug or two, but I'm trying to address what I believe is the underlying question.